# XDocument.Load "Illegal characters in path." Error, but when I test the function there is the XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I get error illegal characters in path with this line of code

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(openBatch.GetOpenBatchSummary("xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx", "", "", ""));
        var summary = from r in doc.Descendants("OpenBatchSummary")
                      select new
                      {
                          PaymentTypeID = r.Element("Payment_Type_ID"),
                          Return = r.Element("Return"),
                          Sale = r.Element("Sale"),
                      };
        foreach (var i in summary)
        {
            ListViewItem it = new ListViewItem(i.PaymentTypeID.ToString());
            it.SubItems.Add(i.Sale.ToString());
            it.SubItems.Add(i.Return.ToString());
            listView1.Items.Add(it);
        }
```

But when I test the through this line of code there is the xml data's

```
var test = openBatch.GetOpenBatchSummary("xxx", "xxxx", "xxx", "", "", "");
        MessageBox.Show(test);
```

And here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `XDocument.Parse`, not `XDocument.Load`. You are trying to load the content from a file that way.

Comment: can you help me? PLEASE there is another error "ListViewItem it = new ListViewItem(i.PaymentTypeID.ToString());" THANKS :)

Comment: @GrayFullBuster Try to change that to: `ListViewItem it = new ListViewItem {Content = i.PaymentTypeID.ToString()};`

Comment: thanks, i just have the wrong value for descendants, my value has "<></>" this, how do i remove that?

Comment: I'm afraid that what I can't help you with that, as I don't have the complete XML document, nor the complete source, nor a detailed error trace.

Comment: I already got the value but it is like this way <Payment_Type_id>Value</Payment_Type_id>

Comment: Replace `i.PaymentTypeID.ToString()` with `(string)i.PaymentTypeID`.